# Прижать элемент XAML к низу панели меню (гамбургер) и убрать "пустоту"

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

Есть станица на которой меню "гамбурегером". Реализовано вот так:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RelativePanel>
        <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="30"
                Content="&#xE700;" Click="HamburgerButton_Click" Background="#FF238072"/>
        <TextBlock Name="TitleTextBlock" RelativePanel.RightOf="HamburgerButton"
                   FontSize="26"
                   FontWeight="Bold" Margin="30 5 0 0" />
    </RelativePanel>

    <SplitView Name="mySplitView" Grid.Row="1" OpenPaneLength="240"
               DisplayMode="CompactInline"  CompactPaneLength="50" Loading="mySplitView_Loading">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <ListBox x:Name="menu" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBoxItem Name="MyPage">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="28" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE77B;" />
                        <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="Моя страница" Margin="10 0 0 0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="Groups">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="28" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE716;"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="Сообщества" Margin="10 0 0 0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>

                <ListBoxItem Name="Login" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="Login_Image" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="30" Height="30" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Login_Icon" FontSize="28" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE8FA;"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Login_Text" FontSize="24" Text="Войти" Margin="10 0 0 0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <Frame Name="Content" />
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
</Grid>
```

Выглядит это все вот так: [image: Текущий вид меню]

Хотелось бы получить меню которое будет выезжать полностью ( в моем случае остается черный кусок справа от кнопки "гамбургера") как вот тут и прижатый к низу элемент: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался убирать TextBlock справа от кнопки и немного играться с атрибутами пока ничего не вышло путного.

Answer (score 2):

Кнопка и SplitView находятся в разных строках грида. Сделайте их в одной строке, а у содержимого панели SplitView делайте отступ, чтобы кнопка не перекрывала пункты меню. Ну и Zindex у кнопки повысьте, чтобы всегда поверх была.

Comment: С кнопкой я делал не совсем возможно правильно решение, но сделал просто кнопку как ListBoxItem. Вот теперь не могу последний пункт прижать к низу.

Comment: На примере второго скриншота: Нижний пункт не относится к основному меню. Сделайте в панели меню тот же грид с несколькими строками. В верхнюю строку поместите поиск, во вторую - листвью с основным меню, в третью - кнопку "Плейлисты", в четвертую - кнопку настроек. Вы всё пытаетесь уместить в один список, но это разные элементы.

Comment: Я пытался следовать вашему совету, но в силу малого опыта, не смог добиться нужного результата в полной мере. Вот что вышло на данный момент : [скриншот](http://vk.cc/5uksvO) .
Вот и [код](http://pastebin.com/3VAiiG2d)

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо!